# Increasing number of Fragments despite replace?

Tags: android, android-fragments

so I'm still struggling with `Fragments` and orientation changes. I have a main `Activity` with a `ListFragment` on the left that either loads the selected action in the `FrameLayout` on the right or starts a new activity (quite standard and I'm trying use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Layout) as a guideline), using a function.

The problem is that each time I go from portrait to landscape, a new `Fragment` is created but the old one is not replaced, despite using `replace(...)`.

Here is the code of the function, that gets called when an item from the list is selected or on `onStart()` of the MainActivity (without all the debug lines):

```
public void startDataOp(int opId) {
    FrameLayout flright = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.iManageDataActionFrameLayout); 
    currentDataOp = opId;
    if(orientation.equals("default")) { // start intents for each data operation, orientation is set earlier
        switch (opId)   {
            case -1:
            { /* nothing to do here */ }
            break;
            case 0: {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(this.getApplicationContext(), AImportFile.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 313);
            }
            break;
            // ...
            default:
                break;
        }           
    }   
    else {  // landscape, so load them in the FrameLayout: iManageDataActionFragment
        int flrichi = -1;
        if(flright != null) { flrichi = flright.getChildCount(); }

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        switch (opId) 
        {
            case -1:
            {
                if(flrichi != -1)
                {
                    flright.removeAllViews();
                    if(flright.getVisibility() != View.GONE) { flright.setVisibility(View.GONE); }  
                }
            }
            break;
            case 0:
            {
                if(flrichi == 0) {  // this gets only called the first time
                    flright.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ft.add(R.id.iManageDataActionFrameLayout, FImportFile.newInstance(counter, orientation), "tDataOpsRightAction");
                }
                else {  // this gets called after the first time and yet the number of Fragments keeps increasing
                    ft.replace(R.id.iManageDataActionFrameLayout, FImportFile.newInstance(counter, orientation), "tDataOpsRightAction"); 
                }
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
            break;
            // ...
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that Logcat does indeed indicate that the correct option is chosen (`ft.replace(...)`) and the child count of the right FrameLayout is 1 before and after the commit. However, LogCat tells me that the Fragments that are replaced are still there!

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance for your help!